# how can I unit test my font-face rules?

Tags: buffers, font-lock

I would like to unit test my font-face keyword rules against some source code data sets.

It sounds like it should be quite easy: open the source file, enable the mode, force fontification, dump out the properties to a file and then compare. However, it is only possible (AFAICT) to `font-lock-fontify-buffer` which has an ambiguous region... it may just be the visible region.

Is there a way to force fontification of every single character in the buffer, even when it is too large to view? Or are the docs just ambiguous, but it actually does what I want?

The ideal situation would be if somebody has already written a test framework for this, in which case, please let me know!

Maybe I could hack it with a custom `font-lock-mark-block-function` or `font-lock-fontify-region-function` to select the entire buffer just for the test, but that limits my ability to test user interactions.

Comment: `(font-lock-ensure (point-min) (point-max))`?

Comment: @CroadLangshan thank you! I may be overthinking this :-D

Comment: Have a look at the comment in the `declare` for `font-lock-fontify-buffer` in `font-lock.el`

Comment: @CroadLangshan LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed an existing test framework: https://github.com/Lindydancer/faceup

Make sure to check out the author's other packages, many of them are related to the intricacies of font-lock.

Answer (score 0):

[groovy-mode](https://github.com/Groovy-Emacs-Modes/groovy-emacs-modes) has several unit tests for font face rules. There's a macro for ensuring the whole buffer is fontified, then we check the face at different positions in the resulting buffer.

```lisp
(defmacro with-highlighted-groovy (src &rest body)
  "Insert SRC in a temporary groovy-mode buffer, apply syntax highlighting,
then run BODY."
  (declare (indent 1) (debug t))
  `(with-temp-buffer
     (insert ,src)
     (goto-char (point-min))
     ;; Activate groovy-mode, but don't run any hooks. This doesn't
     ;; matter on Travis, but is defensive when running tests in the
     ;; current Emacs instance.
     (delay-mode-hooks (groovy-mode))
     ;; Ensure we've syntax-highlighted the whole buffer.
     (if (fboundp 'font-lock-ensure)
         (font-lock-ensure)
       (with-no-warnings
         (font-lock-fontify-buffer)))
     ,@body))

(ert-deftest groovy-highlight-triple-double-quote ()
  ;; Ensure we handle single " correctly inside a triple-double-quoted string.
  (with-highlighted-groovy "x = \"\"\"foo \" bar \"\"\""
    (search-forward "bar")
    (should (eq (face-at-point) 'font-lock-string-face))))
```